# dropzone.js when count($_FILES["file"]) always get 5

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

i just using this dropzone.js and find this a bug or i do something wrong?
the documentation dont have any demo.

i already searched for this and not see any question / issue regarding this

my html code:

```
<button id="submit-all" class="btn btn-primary">Submit all files</button> // for upload all
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone">
  <label>Username:<input type="text" name="uname"/> </label> // only for test
  <label>Password:<input type="text" name="pass"/> </label> // only for test
  <div id="dropzonePreview"></div> 
</form>
```

for the js:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

// Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
autoProcessQueue: false,
parallelUploads:100,

init: function() {
var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
myDropzone = this; // closure

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
});

// You might want to show the submit button only when 
// files are dropped here:
this.on("addedfile", function(file) {

// Create the remove button
var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button class='removebutton'>Remove file</button>");


// Capture the Dropzone instance as closure.
var _this = this;

// Listen to the click event
removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
// Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

// Remove the file preview.
_this.removeFile(file);
// If you want to the delete the file on the server as well,
// you can do the AJAX request here.
});

// Add the button to the file preview element.
file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
});

this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
// Handle the responseText here. For example, add the text to the preview element:
$(".removebutton").hide();
});


}
};
```

my upload.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["count"] = count($_FILES["file"]); // this always print 5
for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES["file"]) ; $i++) { 

$target_dir = "gambar/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
// uplaod image
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$_SESSION["uname"] = $uname;
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION["pass"] = $pass;
}
```

When i print the session for count it always give me 5 even if i upload 7 file or 2 file.

any reason why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by doing `count($_FILES["the_first_file_input_name"])` you are not counting the number files uploaded, but the count of properties of the file itself

Looking at PHP docs the $_FILES array takes the form of an associative array, each file item being itself an associative array of 5 standard members:

```
Array => (
          [file1] => Array (
                            [name] => SomeFile.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/tmp_name
                            [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
                            [size] => 12345
                           )
          [file2] => Array (
                            [name] => SomeOtherFile.jpg
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/other_tmp_name
                            [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
                            [size] => 123456
                           )
         )
```

You need to count the files array instead `count($_FILES)`

**EDIT**

It also looks like you have configured drozonejs to process the queued files using parallel individual requests, one per file upload, so this count would now be 1, but executed n files times. There is an option to allow multiple files in a single upload request instead `uploadMultiple: true`
 http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-uploadMultiple

Comment: i try this but its give me 1 , i upload 7 file its only count 1 using this 
    count($_FILES)

Comment: Needs some extra config for multiple files in single request, see edit

Comment: okay thanks for the help that what i am missing the uploadMultiple: true